# How to fix "The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly" when making a HttpWebRequest to certain sites

Tags: c#, http, webrequest

I cannot receive a response from certain sites like https://www.adidas.ca but have no problem reaching https://www.google.ca.

I've tried the following:

1. Setting SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;

2. Setting the KeepAlive = true;

3. Setting the appropriate Headers such as, UserAgent, Accept-Encoding, and Accept-Language.

4. Using Fiddler and Post-Man to see the difference in the request I make manually and from code to see what could be the difference (I couldn't find anything).

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | 
SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | 
SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.adidas.com/");
request.KeepAlive = true;
request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) 
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36";
request.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "identity;q=1, *;q=0");
request.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
request.Method = "GET";
request.Accept = "*/*";

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

I expected to receive a 200 response, like I did from https://www.google.ca/, but instead receive an error: 

**System.Net.WebException: 'The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly.'**

Comment: Use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler.  Compare the results using a browser manually going to the site vs using your c# app.   Compare the http headers and make you app look like the browser results.

Comment: @jdweng I've already tried to use fiddler and tried to replicate the request header the best I could, but the same result. It is possible I may have missed something, I'll give it another go.

Comment: HTTP uses TCP as transport layer.  A TCP max size ~1500 bytes so each HTTP message can consist of one or more TCP datagrams.  The sniffer shows both the TCP and combined HTTP message.  If the connection is closed then you would see a FIN in one of the TCP datagrams.

Comment: @jdweng I apologize as I am not network savvy/didn't really understand what you were trying to explain, but could you elaborate on how this is related to my issue? Are you saying that the site I can't connect to is purposely sending me a FIN when trying to make requests to it?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue by using fiddler and enabling the **Decrypt HTTPS Traffic** option, so that I could see the request being made and translated it to C# code.

Comment: What were the exact changes in the request you made?